# Yii model overriding

Tags: model, yii

is it possible to override the methods in the yii model. for example i have a model name **Books** and i need to override all the rules written in the Model. now the Books model have 3 rules defined. what i do is make a new class BooksExt extends the Books model.

```
class BooksExt extends Books {
 public function rules() {
   return array();
   // i am not using the parent::rules() inside this. 
   // i dont need to use the rules for this model.
 }
 public function search() {
   return 'search override';
   // does this function also get override.
 }
}
```

does i write a blank rules() method removes all the rules and when i call

```
$model = new AccountsPrefferredSuppliersExt;
$model->search();
```

its printing search override. does it accept the rules as empty array. 
friends can you just check and please responds.

thanks in advance.. have a nice day

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking.  Yes, you can overwrite functions in Books by putting them in BooksExt. Your best bet is just to try it out!

Comment: yes i tried it. waiting for some others experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, method rules() in BooksExt will return an empty array.
[Read about Class Hierachies And Overriding](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Class-Hierachies-And-Overriding.html).